# AFNetworking PUT request Error 400

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to make a PUT request using AFNetworking. There is a JSON on a remote location, which I want to update with the request.

I have managed to serialize my object into JSON, and I have put it an NSDictionary object:

```
NSDictionary *container = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self notifications] forKey:@"notifications"];
```

This way when I print out the container using NSLog, I get precisely the JSON I want to send.

Then I try to use AFNetworking for my request:

```
AFHTTPClient *putClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://creativemind.appspot.com"]];
        [putClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *putRequest = [putClient requestWithMethod:@"PUT"
                                                                path:@"/notifications"
                                                          parameters:container];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *putOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:putRequest];
        [putClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
        [putOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
        [putOperation start];
```

When I try this solution, I get the following error message:

> 2013-08-10 16:10:40.741 NotificationReader[1132:c07] Error: Error
>   Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in
>   (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x75c89e0
>   {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"cause":null,"class":"java.lang.NumberFormatException","localizedMessage":"null","message":"null"},
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://creativemind.appspot.com/notifications>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://creativemind.appspot.com/notifications,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

I think it's important to note that when I try the same request with nil parameters, I get te same error message. I also tried to perform a GET request on the same JSON to check if I can reach it and it works perfectly. I really have no idea what I could do. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error message indicates that the server does some processing (in Java) and then fails with a *NumberFormatException*. Thus, the error message most likely isn't generated by the web server but some code of this specific web service. So the URL, possibly the request headers and the method are most likely okay. The exception could indicate that the JSON parsing fails. Could it be that the structure or data types of your JSON doesn't match what the web service expects? Have you tried to use Fiddler or a similar tool to test the JSON message directly?

Comment: @Codo no I haven't tried anything like that (haven't used any of those tools before). Maybe it helps a bit if I clear up the process:
I need to download and parse a JSON from the web service, modify some properties, then send the new JSON back with a PUT request. In this current state, the JSON I download, and the one I want to send back is exactly the same (I'm only experimenting with these requests), so it would be really weird if the server didn't find my JSON all right.